# jQuery: click function is not catching the click event on hyperlink

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following piece of code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('body').on('click', 'a.wishlist_item', function(){
            alert('asas');
            return false;
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="wishlist_item" id="wishlist_item" href="#" >Add to wishlist</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is supposed to alert when I click on the hyperlink with wishlist_item class. but its not working.. is there anything that I may be doing wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind the event after the element exists. Use the `ready` event to run the code when all the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'a.wishlist_item', function(e){
    alert('asas');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot man.. its working fine now.. saved me a lot of time !!